# Jenkins script how to compare two string variables

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

1. def pname = "`netstat -ntlp|grep 8080|awk '{printf \$7}'|cut -d/ -f2`"
2. sh "echo $pname" \ java
3. if ("java".equals(pname)) { sh "echo 1111" }

The process corresponding to port 8080 is a java process, and the 2nd line print "java". But the body of the if statement just doesn't execute.

Comment: How are you executing "`netstat -ntlp|grep 8080|awk '{printf \$7}'|cut -d/ -f2`"? It would be helpful if you show the full pipeline.

Comment: @ycr def pname = "\`netstat -ntlp|grep 8080|awk '{printf \$7}'|cut -d/ -f2\`"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be not executing the command correctly. Please refer to the following sample. Please note the `returnStdout: true` to return output of the command.

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('Test') {
            steps {
                script {
                    def pname = sh(returnStdout: true, script: "netstat -ntlp|grep 8080|awk '{printf \$7}'|cut -d/ -f2").trim()
                    if (pname == "java") { 
                        echo "echo 1111" 
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try
"==" for equal
or you can read doc.
https://groovy-lang.org/operators.html#_relational_operators

Comment: I tried, but it still doesn't work.